# Laravel validation for individual input fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

I am using ajax calls in my jquery to send user input from my blade to my controller.

I have an input field

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputProfilePage" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"
           value="{{ Auth::user()->fname }}">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputProfilePage" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"
           value="{{ Auth::user()->lname }}">
  </div>
```

fname is for firstname, lname is for lastname

In my jquery I have a call

```
$('.selectProfilePage').change(function(){
          var val = $(this).val();
          var field = $(this).attr('id');
          updateProfilePage(val, field);
      });
```

field is the name of the field, val is the value the user entered into the input.

updateProfilePage is an ajax call

```
function updateProfilePage(val, field) {
          $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/userprofilepage',
              data: {
                  val: val,
                  field: field
              },
              success: function (msg) {
                  console.log("Profile page has been updated:" + val);
              },
              error: function (msg) {
                  console.log("Profile page has not been updated:" + msg);
              }
          });
      }
```

In my routes file this calls my store function.  What I am struggling with is how to validate the value the user has entered.  Here is my store method in my controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'val' => 'alpha'
            ]);
    }
```

If the user enters anything that is not alphabetic I want to print out an error message on my blade.

I added the following code to my blade but the error still does not appear

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
   <ul>
       @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
           <li>{{$error}}</li>
       @endforeach
   </ul>
</div>
```

So what am I doing wrong?  I want to get the error to show up in my blade if the user inputs anything that is not alphabetic in the input for firstname of lastname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blade syntax is generated by the server every time the page is loaded, as you send the form in ajax the page is not reloaded, to add the error in your alert box I would do something like this: (Not tested)

```
function updateProfilePage(val, field) {
          $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/userprofilepage',
              data: {
                  val: val,
                  field: field
              }
          }).done(function () {
                $('.alert').find('ul').append('<li>Profile page has been updated:' + data + '</li>');
          }).fail(function () {
                $('.alert').find('ul').append('<li>Profile page has not been updated:' + data + '</li>');
          }).always(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
          });
      }
```